# How to use character vector in filter on a database connection in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, mariadb, dbplyr

**EDIT: I found my error in the example below. I made a typo in `stored_group` in filter. It works as expected.**

I want to use a character value to filter a database table. I use `dplyr` functions directly on the connection object. See my steps below.

I connected to my MariaDB database:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), 
                 dbname = mariadb.database,
                 user = mariadb.username,
                 password = mariadb.password,
                 host = mariadb.host,
                 port = mariadb.port)
```

Then I want to use a filter on a table in the database, by using `dplyr` code directly on the connection above:

```
stored_group <- "some_group"
con %>% 
  tbl("Table") %>% 
  select(id, group) %>%
  filter(group == stored_group) %>%
  collect()
```

I got a error saying `Unknown column 'stored_group' in 'where clause'`. So I used `show_query()` like this:

```
stored_group <- "some_group"
con %>% 
  tbl("Table") %>% 
  select(id, group) %>%
  filter(group == stored_group) %>%
  show_query()
```

And I got:

```
<SQL>
SELECT `id`, `group`
FROM `Table`
WHERE (`group` = `stored_group`)
```

In translation, `stored_group` is seen as a column name instead of value in R. How do I prevent this?

On normal data.frames in R this works. Like:

```
stored_group <- "some_group"
data %>% 
  select(id, group) %>%
  filter(group == stored_group)
```

I just tested the solution below, and it works. But my database table will grow. I want to filter directly on the database before collecting.

```
stored_group <- "some_group"
con %>% 
  tbl("Table") %>% 
  select(id, group) %>%
  collect() %>%
  filter(group == stored_group)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with mariaDB. Il works with PostgreSQL although the query is strange :  `    > driver <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")  
> base <- dbConnect(driver, dbname="postgres", host="localhost", port=5432, user=USER, password=PASSWORD)  
> q1 <- "SUEDE"  
> base %>% tbl("pays") %>% select(nom,pays) %>% filter(nom==q1) %>% show_query  
<SQL>  
SELECT *  
FROM (SELECT "nom", "pays"  
FROM "pays") "myxyucaigu"  
WHERE ("nom" = 'SUEDE')  
>  `

Comment: @Nicolas2, ah thanks! I used PostgreSQL last year and I remembered this example worked in PostgreSQL. So I was suprised that for MariaDB it did not.

Comment: @MrH Have you tried with `RMySQL::MySQL()`? (even though `RMySQL` is being deprecated in favor of `RMariaDB`)

Comment: @Aurèle I tried it as well. Thanks for your suggestion! I found my error which was not related to the driver. I had a typo in `stored_group` in the filter. But thanks to your suggestion I found it!